# Отображение одного div только если выбран один из двух чекбоксоа

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть форма, несколько полей и нужный блок div,id="vcheck"и 2 радио,с одним класом например checkss,но все остальные значения разные (и айди тоже).Как можно сделать, чтобы див (один блок) отображался только если один из двух чекбоксов выбран (любой из двух)? Рассматриваю любой вариант,мне просто рабочий пример надо

Comment: для начала привести пример верстки, и код где вы на чекбоксы вешаете обработчик клика и пытаетесь поменять видимость блока в нем.

Comment: @Ivan, это же базис, как это можно не знать? почитайте доки по addEventListener и getElementBy*.

Comment: Если можно, дайте пожалуйста ответ конкретный,как это сделать.стили,код,скрипт,спасибо

Comment: То есть - просто чекбоксы,и див, который отображается если любой из двух чекбоксов выбран

Comment: @dasauser на самом деле тут хватит css

Comment: Если можно, дайте пожалуйста ответ конкретный,как это сделать.стили,код,скрипт,спасибо

Comment: Вот пример https://codepen.io/hardiksolanki/pen/BKrKGa который должен натолкнуть на решение

Comment: человек не хочет чтоб его толкали к решению, он ясно написал что хочет получить "стили код скрипт"

Comment: Vasily Koshelev спасибо

Comment: Херогое ТЗ товарищ

Answer (score 0):

На.

```css
#vchecked {
  display: none;
  background-color: coral;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#radio2:checked~#vchecked {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" class="checkss"><label for="radio1">Check #1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" class="checkss"><label for="radio2">Check #2</label>

<br> div below will be shown only if check radio #2...
<br>
<div id="vchecked">Yep!</div>
```